# What happened to the Rx Switch() operator?

Tags: system.reactive

I am working my way through the Hands-On-Labs for reactive extensions (Rx HOL .NET.pdf) which I downloaded from the data developer center ([here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=208528)) a few days ago.

I added these references to my project, using NuGet:

```
System.Reactive 1.0.10621.0

System.Reactive.Windows.Forms 1.0.10621.0
```

I'm almost done with the labs, but I've hit a snag trying to implement the .Switch() example, Visual Studio can't locate the extension method:

> 'System.IObservable'
>   does not contain a definition for
>   'Switch' and no extension method
>   'Switch' accepting a first argument of
>   type
>   'System.IObservable'
>   could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

Now I know this Hands On Labs document is out of date, because certain things have been renamed (`FromEvent` became `FromEventPattern`) and certain things were removed (`RemoveTimeStamp`) and this document does not reflect that.  For the life of me I cannot guess what they renamed `Switch` to be, or figure out what assembly they might have moved it to, or find a comprehensive list of release notes that indicate it was removed.

Anyone know where I can find `Switch` and what it's current name is?

Comment: Thank you for providing a link to the Hand-On-Labs PDF.

Comment: Just so you know, FromEventPattern is not a renaming of FromEvent. FromEvent is still very much alive. Here is a great explanation of the difference between them - https://stackoverflow.com/a/19896246/540156

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `Switch` extension method doesn't extend `IObservable<T>` - it extends `IObservable<IObservable<T>>`. The full signature is:

```
IObservable<TSource> Switch<TSource>(this IObservable<IObservable<TSource>> sources)
```

Try typing `Observable.Empty<IObservable<object>>().` and see if `Switch` appears then.

If not, check your `using` namespace declarations.

Comment: Thanks.  The original example was a `SelectMany` -> `TakeUntil`, I didn't notice that they had changed `from x in foo from y in bar(x)` to `from x in foo select bar(x)`, after using the second form, Switch appeared.

Comment: Yep - you usually use Switch after a Select, just like how SelectMany is really just Merge after a Select