# How to use Observable.FromEvent instead of FromEventPattern and avoid string literal event names

Tags: .net, winforms, system.reactive

I'm learning my way around Rx within WinForms, and have the following code:

```
// Create an observable from key presses, grouped by the key pressed
var groupedKeyPresses = Observable.FromEventPattern<KeyPressEventArgs>(this, "KeyPress")
                                  .Select(k => k.EventArgs.KeyChar)
                                  .GroupBy(k => k);

// Increment key counter and update user's display
groupedKeyPresses.Subscribe(keyPressGroup =>
{
    var numPresses = 0;
    keyPressGroup.Subscribe(key => UpdateKeyPressStats(key, ++numPresses));
});
```

This works/runs perfectly, streams in the KeyPress events, groups by the key pushed, and then keeps track of how many times each key was pushed and calls an `UpdateKeyPressStats` method with the key and new number of presses. Ship it!

However, I'm not a fan of the `FromEventPattern` signature, due to the string literal reference to the event.  So, I figured I'd try `FromEvent` instead.

```
// Create an observable from key presses, grouped by the key pressed
var groupedKeyPresses = Observable.FromEvent<KeyPressEventHandler, KeyPressEventArgs>(h => this.KeyPress += h, h => this.KeyPress -= h)
                                  .Select(k => k.KeyChar)
                                  .GroupBy(k => k);

// Increment key counter and update user's display
groupedKeyPresses.Subscribe(keyPressGroup =>
{
    var numPresses = 0;
    keyPressGroup.Subscribe(key => UpdateKeyPressStats(key, ++numPresses));
});
```

So, the only change was swapping out `Observable.FromEventPattern` with `Observable.FromEvent` (and the path in the `Select` LINQ query to get the `KeyChar`). The rest, including the `Subscribe` methods are identical.  However, at run time with the second solution I get:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot bind to the target method because its
>   signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the
>   delegate type.

What is causing this runtime exception and how should I avoid it?

- GUI: WinForms
- Rx & Rx-WinForms Version: 2.1.30214.0 (via Nuget)
- Target Framework: 4.5

Answer (score 114, accepted):

#### Summary

The first point to make is that you don't actually need to use `Observable.FromEvent` to avoid the string literal reference. This version of `FromEventPattern` will work:

```
var groupedKeyPresses =
    Observable.FromEventPattern<KeyPressEventHandler, KeyPressEventArgs>(
        h => KeyPress += h,
        h => KeyPress -= h)
        .Select(k => k.EventArgs.KeyChar)
        .GroupBy(k => k);
```

If you do want to make `FromEvent` work, you can do it like this:

```
var groupedKeyPresses =
    Observable.FromEvent<KeyPressEventHandler, KeyPressEventArgs>(
        handler =>
        {
            KeyPressEventHandler kpeHandler = (sender, e) => handler(e);
            return kpeHandler;
        }, 
        h => KeyPress += h,
        h => KeyPress -= h)
        .Select(k => k.KeyChar)
        .GroupBy(k => k);
```

Why? It is because the `FromEvent` operator exists to work with any event delegate type.

The first parameter here is a conversion function that connects the event to the Rx subscriber. It accepts the OnNext handler of an observer (an `Action<T>`) and returns a handler compatible with the underlying event delegate that will invoke that OnNext handler. This generated handler can then be subscribed to the event.

I never liked [the offical MSDN documentation for this function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229241.aspx), so here is an expanded explanation that walks through the usage of this function piece by piece.

### The Lowdown on Observable.FromEvent

The following breaks down why `FromEvent` exists and how it works:

#### Review of how .NET event subscriptions work

Consider how .NET events work. These are implemented as delegate chains. Standard event delegates follow the pattern of `delegate void FooHandler(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)`, but in actuality events can work with *any* delegate type (even those with a return type!). We subscribe to an event by passing in an appropriate delegate to a special function that adds it to a delegate chain (typically via the += operator), or if no handlers are subscribed yet, the delegate becomes the root of the chain. This is why we must do a null check when raising an event.

When the event is raised, (typically) the delegate chain is invoked so that each delegate in the chain is called in turn. To unsubscribe from a .NET event, the delegate is passed into a special function (typically via the -= operator) so that it can be removed from the delegate chain (the chain is walked until a matching reference is found, and that link is removed from the chain).

Let's create a simple but non-standard .NET event implementation. Here I am using the less common *add/remove* syntax to expose the underlying delegate chain and enable us to log subscription and unsubscription. Our non-standard event features a delegate with parameters of an integer and a string rather than the usual `object sender` and `EventArgs` subclass:

```
public delegate void BarHandler(int x, string y);

public class Foo
{  
    private BarHandler delegateChain;

    public event BarHandler BarEvent
    {
        add
        {
            delegateChain += value;                
            Console.WriteLine("Event handler added");
        }
        remove
        {
            delegateChain -= value;
            Console.WriteLine("Event handler removed");
        }
    }

    public void RaiseBar(int x, string y)
    {
        var temp = delegateChain;
        if(temp != null)
        {
            delegateChain(x, y);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Review of how Rx subscriptions work

Now consider how Observable streams work. A subscription to an observable is formed by calling the `Subscribe` method and passing an object that implements the `IObserver<T>` interface, which has the `OnNext`, `OnCompleted` and `OnError` methods called by the observable to handle events. Additionally the `Subscribe` method returns an `IDisposable` handle that can be disposed to unsubscribe.

More typically, we use convenience extension methods that overload `Subscribe`. These extensions accept delegate handlers conforming to the `OnXXX` signatures and transparently create an `AnonymousObservable<T>` whose `OnXXX` methods will invoke those handlers.

#### Bridging .NET and Rx events

So how can we create a bridge to extend .NET events into the Rx observable streams? The result of calling Observable.FromEvent is to create an IObservable whose `Subscribe` method acts like a factory that will create this bridge.

The .NET event pattern has no representation of completed or error events. Only of an event being raised. In other words, we must only bridge three aspects of the event that map to Rx as follows:

1. **Subscription** e.g a call to `IObservable<T>.Subscribe(SomeIObserver<T>)` maps to `fooInstance.BarEvent += barHandlerInstance`.
2. **Invocation** e.g. a call to `barHandlerInstance(int x, string y)` maps to `SomeObserver.OnNext(T arg)`
3. **Unsubscription** e.g. assuming we preserve the returned `IDisposable` handler from our `Subscribe` call into a variable called `subscription`, then a call to `subscription.Dispose()` maps to `fooInstance.BarEvent -= barHandlerInstance`.

Note that it's only that act of calling `Subscribe` that creates the subscription. So the `Observable.FromEvent` call is returning a factory supporting subscription to, invocation of, and unsubscription from the underlying event. At this point, there is no event subscription taking place. Only at the point of calling `Subscribe` will the Observer be available, along with it's `OnNext` handler. Therefore, the `FromEvent` call must accept factory methods it can use to implement the three bridging actions at the appropriate time.

#### The FromEvent Type Arguments

So now let's consider a correct implementation of `FromEvent` for the above event.

Recall that `OnNext` handlers only accept a single argument. .NET event handlers can have *any* number of parameters. So our first decision is to select a single type to represent event invocations in the target observable stream.

In fact, this can be *any* type you want to appear in your target observable stream. It's the job of the conversion function (discussed shortly) to provide the logic to convert the event invocation into an OnNext invocation - and there's plenty of freedom to decide how this happens.

Here we will map the `int x, string y` arguments of a BarEvent invocation into a formatted string describing both values. In other words we will cause a call to `fooInstance.RaiseBar(1, "a")` to result in an invocation of `someObserver.OnNext("X:1 Y:a")`.

This example should put to rest a very common source of confusion: What do the type parameters of `FromEvent` represent? Here the first type `BarHandler` is *the source .NET event delegate type*, the second type is *the target `OnNext` handler's argument type.* Because this second type is often an `EventArgs` subclass  it's often assumed that it must be some necessary part of the .NET event delegate - a lot of people miss the fact its relevance is really due to the `OnNext` handler. So the first part of our `FromEvent` call looks like this:

```
 var observableBar = Observable.FromEvent<BarHandler, string>(
```

#### The Conversion Function

Now let's consider the first argument to `FromEvent`, the so called conversion function. (Note, some overloads of `FromEvent` omit the conversion function - more on this later.)

The lambda syntax can be truncated quite a bit thanks to type inference, so here's a long-hand version to start with:

```
(Action<string> onNextHandler) =>
{
    BarHandler barHandler = (int x, string y) =>
    {
        onNextHandler("X:" + x + " Y:" + y);
    };
    return barHandler;
}
```

So this conversion function is a *factory function* that when invoked *creates* a handler compatible with the underlying .NET event. The factory function accepts an `OnNext` delegate. This delegate should be invoked by the returned handler in response to the handler function being invoked with the underlying .NET event arguments. The delegate will be invoked with the result of converting the .NET event arguments to an instance of the `OnNext` parameter type. So from the above example we can see that the factory function will be called with an `onNextHandler` of type `Action<string>` - it must be invoked with a string value in response to each .NET event invocation. The factory function creates a delegate handler of type `BarHandler` for the .NET event that handles event invocations by invoking the `onNextHandler` with a formatted string created from the arguments of the corresponding event invocation.

With a bit of type inference, we can collapse the above code to the following equivalent code:

```
onNextHandler => (int x, string y) => onNextHandler("X:" + x + " Y:" + y)
```

The conversion function therefore fulfils *some* of the event Subscription logic in providing a function to create an appropriate event handler, and it also does the work to map the .NET event invocation to the Rx `OnNext` handler invocation.

As mentioned previously, there are overloads of `FromEvent` that omit the conversion function. This is because it is not required if the event delegate is already compatible with the method signature required for `OnNext`.

#### The add/remove handlers

The remaining two arguments are the addHandler and removeHandler that are responsible for subscribing and unsubscribing the created delegate handler to the actual .NET event - Assuming we have an instance of `Foo` called `foo` then the completed `FromEvent` call looks like this:

```
var observableBar = Observable.FromEvent<BarHandler, string>(
    onNextHandler => (int x, string y) => onNextHandler("X:" + x + " Y:" + y),
    h => foo.BarEvent += h,
    h => foo.BarEvent -= h);
```

It's up to us to decide how the event we are going to bridge is procured - so we provide the add and remove handler functions that expect to be provided the created conversion handler. The event is typically captured via a closure, as in the above example where we close over a `foo` instance.

Now we have all the pieces for the `FromEvent` observable to fully implement subscription, invocation and unsubscription.

#### Just one more thing...

There's one final piece of glue to mention. Rx optimizes the subscriptions to the .NET event. In reality, for any given number of subscribers to the observable, just one single subscription is made to the underlying .NET event. This is then multicast to the Rx subscribers via the `Publish` mechanism. It's as if a `Publish().RefCount()` had been appended to the observable.

Consider the following example using the delegate and class defined above:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var foo = new Foo();

    var observableBar = Observable.FromEvent<BarHandler, string>(
        onNextHandler => (int x, string y)
            => onNextHandler("X:" + x + " Y:" + y),
    h => foo.BarEvent += h,
    h => foo.BarEvent -= h);

    var xs = observableBar.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("xs: " + x));
    foo.RaiseBar(1, "First");    
    var ys = observableBar.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("ys: " + x));
    foo.RaiseBar(1, "Second");
    xs.Dispose();
    foo.RaiseBar(1, "Third");    
    ys.Dispose();
}
```

This produces this following output, demonstrating just a single subscription is made:

```
Event handler added
xs: X:1 Y:First
xs: X:1 Y:Second
ys: X:1 Y:Second
ys: X:1 Y:Third
Event handler removed
```

I do help this helps clears up any lingering confusion over how this complex function works!

Comment: Agree, but then what's the point of the first version of the FromEvent method?  One that does not take user's conversion function?  Seems like RX is attempting to provide a default implementation of this conversion (thanks, ILSpy) ReflectionUtils.CreateDelegate<TDelegate>(onNext, typeof(Action<TEventArgs>).GetMethod("Invoke"));), but it's not creating a good delegate.  Is that right?    The first version, using same signature with the FromEventPattern works.

Comment: `FromEvent` exists to handle all delegate types - including those that don't conform to the standard .NET event pattern. In the event (sorry) that the delegate happens to be an Action<T>, no conversion is necessary. `FromEventPattern` however, only works on conventional event delegates.

Comment: +1 this helped greatly in my understanding of how the conversion function works and getting it to work with ComponentDispatcher.ThreadPreprocessMessage event.

Comment: When using the `FromEvent(...)` and you get Exceptions like `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException` with `System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException` or similar embedded, then are these identications you should write a conversion handler, return same as the event uses (`(sender, args)` combination in returned Observable) or use the `FromEventPattern`.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the string literal event names, use the `nameof` operator:

```
var keyPresses = Observable.FromEventPattern<KeyPressEventArgs>(this, nameof(KeyPress))
                        .Select(k => k.EventArgs.KeyChar)
                        .GroupBy(k => k);
```

instead of hard-coding the event name like

```
var keyPresses = Observable.FromEventPattern<KeyPressEventArgs>(this, "KeyPress")
                        .Select(k => k.EventArgs.KeyChar)
                        .GroupBy(k => k);
```

Note that the `nameof` operator is available for C# 6 or above.