# Callling event function through Observable.FromEvent object

Tags: asp.net, events, c#-4.0, delegates, system.reactive

I am using one delegate and event for the same as below:

```
public delegate void DelgSampledelegate(string status);

public static event DelgSampledelegate sampleEvent;

sampleEvent += new DelgSampledelegate(sample_method);

public void sample_method(string value)
{}
```

Now I wanted to use Rx Extension for above delegate. So I tried below code to create object of `Observable.FromEvent`

```
var objDataUpdated = Observable.FromEvent(h => sampleEvent += h, h => sampleEvent -= h);

var movesSubscription = objDataUpdated.Subscribe(evt => evt.ToString());
```

My aim is to call `'sample_method'` function as I was calling earlier.I know it may be done either via subscribe.Please guide me proper way to do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Observable.FromEvent instead of FromEventPattern and avoid string literal event names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895373/how-to-use-observable-fromevent-instead-of-fromeventpattern-and-avoid-string-lit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't see that you're missing much except the type parameters and actually raising an event to test it:

```
var objDataUpdated = Observable.FromEvent<DelgSampledelegate, string>(
    h => sampleEvent += h,
    h => sampleEvent -= h);

var movesSubscription = objDataUpdated.Subscribe(x => sample_method(x));

// note the preceding line can be shortened to finish
// .Subscribe(sample_method) but I didn't want to make too many leaps

// raise a sampleEvent, will call sample_method("Test")
sampleEvent("Test");
```

See [How to use Observable.FromEvent instead of FromEventPattern and avoid string literal event names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895373/how-to-use-observable-fromevent-instead-of-fromeventpattern-and-avoid-string-lit) for a comprehensive explanation of `FromEvent` - although note the form in this answer needs no conversion function because `DelgSampledelegate`'s signature matches the required `OnNext` signature.