# Observable.FromEvent<> not working with Umbraco ContentService.Published

Tags: c#, events, umbraco, system.reactive

I'm trying to wire up Umbraco events using Rx:

```
Observable.FromEvent<TypedEventHandler<IPublishingStrategy, PublishEventArgs<IContent>>, PublishEventArgs<IContent>>(
h => ContentService.Published += h, h => ContentService.Published -= h).Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
```

But I get an exception from deep within Rx when subscribing:

> Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type.

I can get it to work with a not-so-clean workaround:

```
var subject = new Subject<PublishEventArgs<IContent>>();
ContentService.Published += (sender, args) => subject.OnNext(args);
subject.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
```

But, how can I wire it up using Observable.FromEvent<>?

Comment: Try `FromEventPattern` rather than `FromEvent` - the latter is for non-standard events and the former for events of the "sender, eventargs" variety.

Comment: For a full discussion of how `Observable.FromEvent` works see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895373/how-to-use-observable-fromevent-instead-of-fromeventpattern-and-avoid-string-lit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per suggestion from Enigmativity, this is the solution that works:

```
Observable.FromEventPattern<TypedEventHandler<IPublishingStrategy, PublishEventArgs<IContent>>, PublishEventArgs<IContent>>
            (h => ContentService.Published += h, h => ContentService.Published -= h).Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
```

Comment: I'm getting the same exception when using FromEventPattern...