# How to create IObservable from delegate that does not inherit from EventHandler?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I am using Accord (previously AForge) to capture image frames from a webcam.

These images arrive via a `VideoCaptureDevice.NewFrame` event:

```
public delegate void NewFrameEventHandler(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs);

public class NewFrameEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public Bitmap Frame { get; }

    public NewFrameEventArgs(Bitmap frame);
}
```

The problem is, I tried to use `Observable.FromEvent`, but got lost in the many possible overloads:

```
void Run()
{
    var videoDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);

    VideoCaptureDevice videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice(videoDevices[0].MonikerString);

    // regular way
    videoSource.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(video_NewFrame);

    // intended rx way
    var receivedFrames = Observable.FromEvent(????)    /////////// How?
}

void video_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    // do something
}
```

I know I cannot use `Observable.FromEventPattern`, but don't know what to use instead, much less how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var receivedFrames = Observable.FromEventPattern<NewFrameEventHandler, NewFrameEventArgs>(
  handler => handler.Invoke,
  h => videoSource.NewFrame += h,
  h => videoSource.NewFrame -= h);
```

When I was first learning Rx, I found the following site very helpful: [IntroToRx](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/04_CreatingObservableSequences.html#FromEvent) (link goes to portion where I found this example).

Comment: Actually it worked without the first argument (that is, without the Invoke, and with only the assignment/unassignment arguments).

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this (and tested it in LinqPad)

```
var observable = Observable.FromEvent<NewFrameEventHandler, NewFrameEventArgs>(
    (handler) =>
    {
        NewFrameEventHandler frameHandler = (sender, e) =>
        {
            handler(e);
        };

        return frameHandler;
    },
    eh => videoSource.NewFrame += eh,
    eh => videoSource.NewFrame -= eh
);

observable.Subscribe((frameEventArgs) => { frameEventArgs.Dump(); });
```

It was a nice exercise based on the answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895373/how-to-use-observable-fromevent-instead-of-fromeventpattern-and-avoid-string-lit).

So it uses [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229241(v=vs.103).aspx) of `Observable.FromEvent`.

Happy to know if it could be written more compact.